# VirtualHost files all pointing to first VirtualHost in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: apache2, virtualhost, ubuntu-12.04

So I set up 2 virtual host files, example1.com and example2.com with the following information:

--first file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName  example1.com
    ServerAlias www.example1.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example1.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/example1.com
</VirtualHost>
```

--second file

```
<VirtualHost 127.0.0.1:80>
    ServerName  example2.com
    ServerAlias www.example2.com
    ServerAdmin admin@example2.com
    DocumentRoot    /var/www/example2.com
</VirtualHost>
```

and set up my hosts file to read

```
127.0.0.1 locahost
127.0.0.1 example1.com
127.0.0.1 example2.com
```

But if I try to go to localhost,example1.com or example2.com my browser just sends me to example1.com

the default virtualhost file has:

```
<Directory />
    Options FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
</Directory>
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks MultiViews
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    allow from all
</Directory>
```

Im assuming that the AllowOverride for /var/www takes precedence over the root correct?

So then I later just turned off all my virtual hosts with a2dissite and commented out those lines in the hosts file but half my sites dont work at all now.

One of my wordpress sites cant seem to pull it's css file so its all jacked (it was fine 24 hours ago), a couple of the sites seem to have lost their connection to the DB.

I have no idea whats going on, but everything is jacked.

edit - my original question had both virtualhost files pointing to example1.com, that was a a copy paste fail, the actual files are pointing to legit website URLs

Comment: can you please post the relevant parts of your apache config file as well? I'm thinking their might be an issue if the listener is not declared or the vh configs are not being added.

Answer (score 6):

My best guess without having seen more of your apache config is that you don't have [name-based virtual hosting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/name-based.html) enabled. To do that, include the following in your Apache config:

```
NameVirtualHost *:80
```

IP-based virtual hosting is the default mechanism Apache uses without that directive.

By the way, if you're doing that, the argument of `<VirtualHost>` blocks has to match that of the `NameVirtualHost` directive, so use this instead:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
```

If you're going to be dealing with a lot of different sites on the same box, you might want to take a looks at the documentation for [mod_vhost_alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).